# Using TensorFlow object detection API models at prediction

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-slim

I have used the TensorFlow [object detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/4f32535fe7040bb1e429ad0e3c948a492a89482d/research/object_detection) to train the SSD Inception model from scratch. The evaluation script shows that the model has learned something and now I want to use the model.

I have looked at the object detection [ipynb](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb) that can feed single images to a trained model. However, this is for SSD with MobileNet. I have used the following line (after loading the meta graph) to print the tensor names of the TensorFlow model I trained.

```py
print([str(op.name) for op in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()] )
```

But it does not contain the same input or output tensor names as in the ipynb. I have also searched through the code, but many functions point toward each other and it is difficult to find what I am looking for.

How can I find the tensor names I need? Or is there another method I do not know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the graph, you need to freeze/export it, using [this provided script](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_inference_graph.py). The resulting `.pb` file will contain the nodes you need. I don't know why it's organized like that, but it is.